# Loading Java spark config from yaml file

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, yaml

I have a java spark app in which I instantiate a `SparkConf` object with the required configurations for Spark. Currently, it looks like this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(appName)
    .setMaster(master)
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
    .set....
```

The master and app name come from a `yaml` file which contains app configurations, and the rest of the spark configurations are hardcoded and set one at a time.

My `yaml` file also contains these key/value pairs of configurations for Spark. My other (python) apps are using the spark configs directly from here. It looks like this:

```
spark:
    master: ...
    appname: ... 
    conf:
        spark.mesos.executor.home: '/data/spark'
        spark.executor.memory: '8g'
        spark.network.timeout: '420'
        ... other spark configs
```

I'm wondering if I can use these configs from the `yaml` file to set the spark configs in the code automatically using `setAll()` method provided by `SparkConf`, instead of setting them one at a time.

This is how I'm reading the configs from the `yaml` file currently but it's not working:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> sparkConf = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map<String, String>) ((Map) yaml.get("spark")).get("conf"));
```

How can I load `spark: conf` from the `yaml` file so it can be used by the `setAll()` method? Apparently, the method expects a scala object of type: `Traversable<Tuple2<String, String>>`.

Comment: do you think this is a general Java/Scala problem and has nothing to do with Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "snakeyaml" dependency in your project to read yaml file in java.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
 </dependency>
```

Now if you have "application.yaml" file having configuration defined like you have posted, you can read it and create SparkConf with setAll() method in java like below.

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();  
InputStream is = MySparkApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.yaml");
Map<String, Object> yamlParsers = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(is);
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> spark = (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>) yamlParsers.get("spark"); 
LinkedHashMap<String,String> config = (LinkedHashMap<String,String>) spark.get("conf");
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
             .setAppName((String) spark.get("appname"))
             .setMaster((String) spark.get("master"))
             .setAll(JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap(config));
```

Comment: thanks a lot , if we have "application.yaml" in some external folder and its path is dynamically set ...how to pass the file path dynamically into spark job ?

Answer (score -1):

for jdk8

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> sparkCfg= (LinkedHashMap<>)    spark.get("spark.cfg");
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
sparkCfg.forEach((k,v)->{ conf.set(k, v.toString());});
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: When making answers, it's important to explain and document your solutions, not just post them.